# php next key and value if value not found based on a certain incremental value

Tags: php

I have an array i search for value in array with reading every 5 seconds 
my input is

```
$input = "23:31:13";
```

it should take 23:31:15

```
$array = array
(
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18/06/2014
            [1] => 23:31:10
            [2] =>  68.4

        )
[1] => Array
        (
           [0] => array
            (

             [0] => 18/06/2014
            [1] => 23:31:15
            [2] =>  67.4

        )   
[2] => array(


            [0] => 18/06/2014
            [1] => 23:31:20
            [2] =>  69.4

        ) 

)
```

My Code

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$temp_arr)
{
    if(in_array($input , $temp_arr) )
        {


            $return[$key]=$temp_arr;

        }

}
```

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you want to get closer date based on the input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Round the last segment of `$input` to the nearest `5` before going through your loop:

```
list( $a, $b, $c) = explode( ":", "23:31:13");
$mod = $c % 5;
$input = $a . ':' . $b . ':' . (($mod < 3) ? $c - $mod : $c + (5 - $mod));
```

This causes `$input` to be `23:31:15` for `23:31:13`, which will now match in your `in_array()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$t_input = strtotime($input);
$arr = array_values(array_filter($array, function ($v) use ($t_input) { return strtotime($v[1]) > $t_input; }));
if (count($arr)) $result = $arr[0][1];
```